# What is drawback of AWS Glue Data Catalog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

What is major drawback of AWS Glue Data Catalog? Been asked in one of interview.

Answer (score 0):

That could be answered in a number of ways depending on the wider context. For example:

- It's an AWS managed service, so using it locks you into the AWS
  ecosystem (instead of using a standalone Hive metastore for example)
- It's limited to the data sources supported by the Glue Data Catalog
- It doesn't integrate with third-party authentication and
  authorisation tools like Apache Ranger (as far as I am aware)